# APC Smart-UPS with two battery sets: Regular switches or not?

Tags: ups, battery

I have a Smart-UPS 1500RM in a remote location with two battery packs.

In order to maximize the lifetime of the battery packs, is it better to

- Use one pack until it dies and then hope that the other one is still good
- Switch between the two packs in an interval of 6-12 months?

Comment: What do you mean you have 2 battery packs? Do you mean that you have a spare battery pack?

Comment: Yes, one spare, hot swappable battery pack. Both fairly new.

Comment: Understood. I've never heard of anyone buying a spare and keeping it on hand unused. If it were me, I'd leave the batteries as is and swap in the spare when the UPS notifies you that the battery needs to be replaced. I also wouldn't purchase any additional spare batteries.

Comment: Of course, I wouldn't do on purpose but I have it by coincidence (bought new batteries, few months later UPS broke so replaced UPS but it also had new batteries installed). So I'm trying to decide how to co-maximize the lifetime.